# How to install the module pytorch_lightning.metrics in Raspberry pi3

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to execute a python file which has pytorch with lightning and torchvision modules. But after I downloaded and successfully installed whl file of pytorch in pi3 I am getting same error again and again.
The error is

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_lightning.metrics'
```

Help would be highly appreciated as I am stuck for more than 3 days.
I have installed the modules using pip.

Comment: What is your import command, import only `pytorch_lightning` (`import pytorch_lightning as pl`) and give us the value of `pl.__version__`. Also please update that you've already installed it via `pip` to avoid confusion for potential answerers.

Answer (score 5):

I found maybe the 'pytorch_lightning.metrics' are updated to 'torchmetrics' package, try changing 'import pytorch_lightning.metrics' to 'import torchmetrics'

Answer (score 4):

Use instead:

```
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy
```

Answer (score 3):

Try installing this version

!pip install pytorch-lightning==1.2.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following installation:

```
pip install -q test_tube transformers pytorch-nlp pytorch-lightning==0.9.0
```

Worth trying.